# How to force synchronous soundcloud javascript sdk calls?

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

From a function, I'd like to return a collection of soundcloud sounds using the SoundCloud javascript SDK. However, because soundcloud is using asynchronous requests, the is not possible:

```
function getFavorites() {
    var tracks = [];
    SC.get('/users/1234', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
        tracks.push(obj);
      });
      return tracks;
    });
}
```

How can I return a value from an asychronous request?

Comment: There might be a config option for doing it synchronously, but that's probably not as good as using a callback (which seems to be what you've already got in the code you posted).  Is there a compelling reason why a callback won't work?

Answer (score 0):

The SoundCloud JavaScript SDK does not support synchronous requests. Instead you must handle the results in a callback.